# BindToObject fails when binding to the desktop

Tags: shell

I have a function that displays a list of child folders of a passed parent folder. Since this is shell programming, we use `pidl`s:

```
void ShowChildFolders(PItemIDList parentPidl)
{
   HRESULT hr;

   //Get ahold of the desktop object, the root of the everything
   IShellFolder desktop;
   SHGetDesktopFolder(out desktop);

   //Get the ShellFolder of the passed folder
   IShellFolder folder;
   hr = desktop.BindToObject(parentPidl, null, IID_IShellFolder, out folder);
   OleCheck(hr);

   /*Do what we were going to do...for example
   IEnumIDList list;
   hr = folder.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_FOLDERS, out list);

   ...etc
   */
}
```

I don't control the `pidl` that is passed in. My task is to bind to that `pidl` and display the contents.

The function works great for nearly every folder in the namespace. For example:

```
//Show the contents of a folder
ShowChildFolders(GetFolderLocation(CSIDL_APPDATA));

//Show the contents of a folder
ShowChildFolders(GetFolderLocation(CSIDL_MYPICTURES));

//Show the contents of a folder
ShowChildFolders(GetFolderLocation(CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY));
```

where i'm using pseudo helper-function:

```
PItemIDList GetFolderLocation(Int32 FolderCSIDL)
{
   PItemIDList pidl;
   HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderLocation(0, FolderCSIDL, 0, 0, ref pidl);
   //...snip....

   return pidl;
}
```

## One pidl to fail them all

But there is one pidl that fails. There is one pidl that i am unable to bind to. The call:

```
hr = desktop.BindToObject(parentPidl, null, IID_IShellFolder, out folder);
```

will [fail with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx):

> `E_INVALIDARG` One or more arguments are not valid (0x80070057)

And that pidl is the very first pidl the caller needs, because when showing the user folders: you have to start at the desktop:

```
//Show the contents of a folder
PItemIDList pidlDesktop = GetFolderLocation(CSIDL_APPDATA);
ShowChildFolders(pidlDesktop );
```

How do i bind the desktop to the desktop? We all know that all shell operations *must* start with the desktop folder. It's your only way in:

```
SHGetDesktopFolder(out desktop);
```

## In reality it's a tree

In reality it's a recursive operation. I add items to a tree:

```
void FetchChildFolders(TreeNode parentNode, PItemIDList parentPidl)
{
   SHGetDesktop(desktop);

   desktop.BindToObject(parentPidl, ...);

   //...enumerate child folders, and add them as children of the tree node parentNode
}
```

i add them as the nodes are expanded by the user:

```
void OnTreeNodeExpanding(e)
{
   TreeNode parentNode = e.Node;
   PItemIDList pidl = GetPidlFromNode(e.Node);

   FetchChildFolders(parentNode, pidl);
}
```

And the tree is initially populated with folders in the desktop:

```
FetchChildFolders(null, GetFolderLocation(CSIDL_DESKTOP));
```

Except not, because you cannot bind to the desktop.

## Bonus Chatter

`SHCreateItemFromIDList` also fails when passed the desktop pidl.